# Our Google SQL Master and Replica appear to be out of sync

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

As part of the migration from another cloud provider to Google Cloud we ran a migration which altered a table (doubling the space as it modified the table) after the migration was completed the Replica cleaned itself up again but the Master did not so they appear to have very different sizes:

Master: 49 GB of 74 GB (66.1%)
Replica: 25 GB of 74 GB (33.7%)

Based on the actual data it should take up 25GB. Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: How are you measuring the size? Are you taking the size of the binary logs into consideration?

Comment: It's what's displayed in the Google Cloud Console.

Comment: The total storage includes the space used by binary logs so it's not unexpected that the master would be using more storage.

Comment: We run another mast + slave combo though and it's nothing like this large of a difference... and it only happened after a migration. I'll check it out though

Comment: The size of the binary logs depends on the number/size of data changes so it's expected that the binary logs are going to be large if you are inserting a lot of data in a short period of time.

Comment: I think a lot of the confusion could be eliminated if the storage graph showed a breakdown of storage by data vs binary logs.